# Packaging like jar for pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, jar, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I have a pyspark project with a python script which runs spark-streaming. I've got some external dependencies which I run with `--packages` flag.

However, in scala, we can use maven to download all required packages, make a jar file with the main spark program and have everything in one jar and then just use `spark-submit` to submit it to the cluster (yarn in my case).

Is there any such similar things as `jar` for pyspark?

There is no such information on the official documentation of spark. They just mention use `spark-submit <python-file>` or add `--py-files` but it isn't as professional as a `jar` file.

Any suggestion would be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: With Python you must send the main Python file and other files with the options: py-files (files to place in the pthon environment), --archives (compressed files to be extracted in the working directory of the executors) or --files ( files to be placed in the working directory of the executors). Then, you can create a zip with all you want and use --archives option.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says you can use zip or egg.

> For Python applications, simply pass a .py file in the place of  instead of a JAR, and add Python .zip, .egg or .py files to the search path with --py-files.

[Source](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

You might also find the [other parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30048645/2308683) useful.