# How to import a python file using spark session?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have tried to import another python file in my current pyspark program using Sparkcontext.It was giving me error as multiple spark context cannot run at once.Hence I am using spark session to import my python file.
My code is :

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Recommendation_system').getOrCreate()
txt=spark.addFile('engine.py')
dataset_path = os.path.join('Musical_Instruments_5.json')
app = create_app(txt,dataset_path)
```

I am getting error as follows:

```
AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'addFile'
```

What will be the correct way of importing python file using spark session.

Answer (score 3):

You should use 'addFile' method of  class:

```
  pyspark.SparkContext
```

[API reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.addFile)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question might depend on Spark running in client or cluster mode, as mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38879788/11809911). For Pyspark, an optimal solution might be to add the `--py-files` flag to the environment variable `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` and this will work in any case. This can be done by pointing to your file as follows:

```py
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--py-files "/path/to/file/engine.py" pyspark-shell'
```

You can even specify the path to a `.zip` containing multiple files as mentioned in the official Spark documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html).

That works when using Pyspark from a notebook environment, for example. A more general solution might be to add this file using the option `spark.submit.pyFiles` inside the spark config file `spark-defaults.conf`. This will even work when running your job using `spark-submit` from the command line. Check the spark configuration options [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday, I wanted to write spark jobs in other files and wanted to run them by using singleton spark session so I did this:
*main.py*

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from job1 import spark_job
import os


if __name__=="__main__":
    print("trying to start spark")

    spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').appName("PythonPi").getOrCreate()
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    # to be able to use paths.py in job's files
    sc.addPyFile(os.getcwd()+'/spark_jobs/paths.py')
    spark_job(spark, sc)
    spark.stop()
```

*paths.py*

```
import os


def get_path(file=__file__):
    return os.path.join(os.getcwd(),file)
```

*job1.py*

```
from paths import get_path

data = [('James','','Smith','1991-04-01','M',3000),
  ('Michael','Rose','','2000-05-19','M',4000),
  ('Robert','','Williams','1978-09-05','M',4000),
  ('Maria','Anne','Jones','1967-12-01','F',4000),
  ('Jen','Mary','Brown','1980-02-17','F',-1)
]

columns = ["firstname","middlename","lastname","dob","gender","salary"]

def spark_job(spark,sc):
    sc.addPyFile(get_path(__file__))
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = columns)
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("PERSON_DATA")
    groupDF = spark.sql("SELECT gender, count(*) from PERSON_DATA group by gender")
    groupDF.show()
```

This way I was able to call spark jobs from different files OR add py files in sparkContext

hope it helps someone.