# Spark read file from each node similar to Hadoop's DistribuitedCache

Tags: file, apache-spark, slave

I have a file in master node that should be read by each node. How can I make this possible? In Hadoop's MapReduce I used the

```
DistribuitedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration())
```

How Spark works for file sharing between nodes? Do I have to load file in RAM and broadcast variable? Or can I only to indicate (absolute?) path of file in SparkContext configuration and it becames instantly available for all nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SparkFiles for reading files from distributed cache.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

sc.addFile("/path/to/file.txt")
val pathOnWorkerNode = new Path(SparkFiles.get("file.txt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Look on spark-submit "files" parameter, for example, here:

[Running Spark jobs on a YARN cluster with additional files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047760/running-spark-jobs-on-a-yarn-cluster-with-additional-files)